# The input/output usage limit on my wordpress website has reached it's maximum

Tags: wordpress, usage-statistics

I have recently purchased a hostinger premium plan and the input/output resource usage limit on my website has reached it's maximum. How can I resolve this issue? How can I ensure it does not happen again? I received an email from hostinger about this that is how I found out.

I tried the Litespeed Cache plugin and I also reached out to Hostinger support. They told me that it might a file management issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you get the website analyze using this tool: https://gtmetrix.com/

The result will show what exactly is causing your site to hit the resource usage limit. It could be the database or media files like images/videos needs optimization, minification of CSS and JS.

I recommend also to unload or uninstall plugins and themes that you don't use.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area, is there anyway you can fix this for me? I could not find what is causing this on gtmetrix.com

Comment: I would like to support you however the issue of your comment is a new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question by including the detailed information for example the result after analyzing the site using the tool? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it.

Comment: I have posted a new question with my gtmetrix results